# Base table is wrong, Need to keep few columns as is while moving other columns around

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

TL;DR
Base table is incorrect, need to refine data using query. Final value is incorrect (slightly less) as nesting on itself leading to some records omission as it's a partial join.

Detail-
This is a query that I am trying to write. My original table has a wrong logic and not sure how to get it rectified, hence decided to pivot the correct table using SQL.
Each out_id can have multiple distinct ord_type on any day. Let's assume there are three ord_type-
Alpha, Beta and Gamma (and so on), not necessarily each exists on all days. Some days might have one, some neither, some all three.

Actual data in table:

| dt | out_id | ord_type | identifier1 | Non_Recon_Amnt | act_returns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16/12 | 01 | Alpha | True | 1 | 3 |
| 16/12 | 01 | Beta | False | 2 | 4 |
| 16/12 | 01 | Gamma | False | 3 | 5 |
| 17/12 | 01 | Beta | False | 4 | 6 |
| 17/12 | 01 | Gamma | False | 5 | 7 |
| 18/12 | 01 | Alpha | True | 6 | 8 |
| 18/12 | 01 | Gamma | False | 7 | 9 |

Data I want from Query:

| dt | out_id | ord_type | identifier1 | Non_Recon_Amnt | act_returns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16/12 | 01 | Alpha | True | 1 | 0 |
| 16/12 | 01 | Beta | False | 2 | 7 |
| 16/12 | 01 | Gamma | False | 3 | 5 |
| 17/12 | 01 | Beta | False | 4 | 6 |
| 17/12 | 01 | Gamma | False | 5 | 7 |
| 18/12 | 01 | Alpha | True | 6 | 0 |
| 18/12 | 01 | Gamma | False | 7 | 9 |
| 18/12 | 01 | Beta | False | 0 | 8 |

This is because the very definition of Alpha means act_returns will be 0 and all values under this should ideally be attributed to Beta.

Data my current query gives-

| dt | out_id | ord_type | identifier1 | Non_Recon_Amnt | act_returns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16/12 | 01 | Alpha | True | 1 | 0 |
| 16/12 | 01 | Beta | False | 2 | 7 |
| 16/12 | 01 | Gamma | False | 3 | 5 |
| 17/12 | 01 | Beta | False | 4 | 6 |
| 17/12 | 01 | Gamma | False | 5 | 7 |
| 18/12 | 01 | Alpha | True | 6 | 0 |
| 18/12 | 01 | Gamma | False | 7 | 9 |

You may notice it doesn't replace Alpha's act_returns value with Beta on 18th Dec

---

Full Query:

```
SELECT
    dt AS date_,
    out_id,
    out_name,
    ct,
    ord_type,
    identifier1,
    identifier2,
    SUM(Non_Recon_Amnt),
    SUM(ret_loss),
    SUM(act_returns)

FROM
    (
        SELECT
            dt,
            out_id,
            out_name,
            ct,
            ord_type,
            identifier1,
            identifier2,
            SUM(Non_Recon_Amnt) as Non_Recon_Amnt,
            CASE WHEN ord_type='Alpha' AND identifier1='true' THEN SUM(ret_loss) ELSE 0 END as ret_loss,
            CASE
                WHEN ord_type = 'Alpha' AND identifier1 = 'true' THEN 0
                WHEN ord_type = 'Beta' THEN
                    (
                        SELECT SUM(act_returns)
                        FROM generic_table
                        WHERE dt=G.dt AND out_id=G.out_id
                        AND ord_type = 'Alpha' AND identifier1 = 'true'
                        OR dt=G.dt AND out_id=G.out_id
                        AND ord_type = 'Beta'
                    )
                ELSE SUM(act_returns)
            END AS act_returns,
            FROM
            generic_table G
        WHERE
            dt >= current_date - 30 AND dt < current_date
        GROUP BY
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
    ) AS subquery
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

In my subquery,

```
CASE
                WHEN ord_type = 'Alpha' AND identifier1 = 'true' THEN 0
                WHEN ord_type = 'Beta' THEN
                    (
                        SELECT SUM(act_returns)
                        FROM generic_table
                        WHERE dt=G.dt AND out_id=G.out_id
                        AND ord_type = 'Alpha' AND identifier1 = 'true'
                        OR dt=G.dt AND out_id=G.out_id
                        AND ord_type = 'Beta'
                    )
                ELSE SUM(act_returns)
            END AS act_returns,`
```

since I have used ord_type Beta, if generic table doesn't have Beta on that particular date, it skips them. How to make the solution better?

Comment: Please tag your DBMS (SQL Server, Oracle, etc...) Does this query do what you want it to, and you are just seeing if it can be simplified? If not, please describe the problems with it's result.

Comment: Please format your source data as a table - so that columns line up and it is readable. Also, update your question with the result you are trying to achieve

Comment: Edited requirement. Apologies for column formatting, still cannot figure out how to do it, will look around and sort it.

Comment: Apologies again Matthew, must have been formatting parallelly.

Comment: @SweeneyTodd "since I have used ord_type Beta, if generic table doesn't have Beta on that particular date, it skips them. How to make the solution better?" It'd be helpful if you update your sample such that it captures the problem you are having, dates and all. That way people can tell whether a solution fixes the problem.

Comment: Do you need to UPDATE the table? Or just SELECT from it? Can a partition have a value in Alpha and not Beta? If so, does a Beta row need creating?

Comment: Please read the help page here; [mre] It explains that stackoverflow values ***concrete*** examples, not generalisations with letters representing numbers, etc. Then you can edit your question with a real [mre[

Comment: I just need to select from the base table. Yes, A partition may have value in Alpha and not Beta (or any random combination thereof). Added a better tabular view (though still with letters as I think they convey the idea better).
Thanks for making the question better.

Comment: @SweeneyTodd Quick tip - Stack Overflow has a weird, I'd argue bug, with the table formatting preview. It'll show up fine in the preview, but then to get it working in the question needs another new line after the markdown.

Comment: Wasn't the intention to prove anyone, least of all SO as wrong. Been scratching my head on this problem for hours now and hence SO is kind of last resort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following LEFT JOINs on to a mapping table to duplicate Alpha rows as Beta rows, then uses aggregation and CASE expressions to move the values around as necessary.

```
CREATE TABLE generic_table (
  dt               DATE,
  out_id           INT,
  ord_type         VARCHAR(8),
  identifier1      BOOLEAN,
  non_recon_amnt   INT,
  act_return       INT
);
```

```
INSERT INTO
  generic_table
VALUES
  ('2023-12-16', 1, 'Alpha', True,  1, 3),
  ('2023-12-16', 1, 'Beta',  False, 2, 4),
  ('2023-12-16', 1, 'Gamma', False, 3, 5),
  ('2023-12-17', 1, 'Beta',  False, 4, 6),
  ('2023-12-17', 1, 'Gamma', False, 5, 7),
  ('2023-12-18', 1, 'Alpha', True,  6, 8),
  ('2023-12-18', 1, 'Gamma', False, 7, 9)
;
```

```
SELECT
  g.dt,
  g.out_id,
  COALESCE(map.ord_type,    g.ord_type),
  COALESCE(map.identifier1, g.identifier1),
  SUM(CASE WHEN map.source IS NULL
             OR map.source  = map.ord_type THEN g.non_recon_amnt ELSE 0 END),
  SUM(CASE WHEN map.source  = map.ord_type THEN 0 ELSE g.act_return     END)
FROM
  generic_table        AS g
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
    'Alpha'   AS source,
    'Alpha'   AS ord_type,
    True      AS identifier1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    'Alpha'   AS source,
    'Beta'    AS ord_type,
    False     AS identifier1
)
  AS map
    ON map.source = g.ord_type
GROUP BY
  g.dt,
  g.out_id,
  COALESCE(map.ord_type,    g.ord_type),
  COALESCE(map.identifier1, g.identifier1)
ORDER BY
  g.dt,
  g.out_id,
  COALESCE(map.ord_type,    g.ord_type),
  COALESCE(map.identifier1, g.identifier1)
```

| dt | out_id | coalesce | coalesce | sum | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-12-16 | 1 | Alpha | t | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-12-16 | 1 | Beta | f | 2 | 7 |
| 2023-12-16 | 1 | Gamma | f | 3 | 5 |
| 2023-12-17 | 1 | Beta | f | 4 | 6 |
| 2023-12-17 | 1 | Gamma | f | 5 | 7 |
| 2023-12-18 | 1 | Alpha | t | 6 | 0 |
| 2023-12-18 | 1 | Beta | f | 0 | 8 |
| 2023-12-18 | 1 | Gamma | f | 7 | 9 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y-MBzbFE)

Comment: Very clever. Much more efficient to join to a 2 record result than UNION + NOT EXISTS + SELF JOIN.

Comment: @Error_2646 I just wish Redshift had lateral joins

Comment: This is just perfect. Thanks a lot Matthew.

Answer (score 1):

This is for SQL Server since I don't have redshift. Tried to keep the query as DBMS independent as possible. Certainly this could be done in fewer lines with window functions, rather than the last self-join, but not sure exactly what and how redshift supports.

The idea is to first manufacturer your missing record for 'Beta' on each day. Then later you can self join and define act_returns how you've described.

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/_oqtPxct

```
CREATE TABLE generic_table (
    dt DATE,
    out_id VARCHAR(2),
    ord_type VARCHAR(10),
    identifier1 VARCHAR(5),
    Non_Recon_Amnt INT,
    act_returns INT
);

INSERT INTO generic_table (dt, out_id, ord_type, identifier1, Non_Recon_Amnt, act_returns) VALUES ('2023-12-16', '01', 'Alpha', 'True', 1, 3);
INSERT INTO generic_table (dt, out_id, ord_type, identifier1, Non_Recon_Amnt, act_returns) VALUES ('2023-12-16', '01', 'Beta', 'False', 2, 4 );
INSERT INTO generic_table (dt, out_id, ord_type, identifier1, Non_Recon_Amnt, act_returns) VALUES ('2023-12-16', '01', 'Gamma', 'False', 3, 5);
INSERT INTO generic_table (dt, out_id, ord_type, identifier1, Non_Recon_Amnt, act_returns) VALUES ('2023-12-17', '01', 'Beta', 'False', 4, 6);
INSERT INTO generic_table (dt, out_id, ord_type, identifier1, Non_Recon_Amnt, act_returns) VALUES ('2023-12-17', '01', 'Gamma', 'False', 5, 7);
INSERT INTO generic_table (dt, out_id, ord_type, identifier1, Non_Recon_Amnt, act_returns) VALUES ('2023-12-18', '01', 'Alpha', 'True', 6, 8);
INSERT INTO generic_table (dt, out_id, ord_type, identifier1, Non_Recon_Amnt, act_returns) VALUES ('2023-12-18', '01', 'Gamma', 'False', 7, 9);


with with_mocked_missing_beta_record as (
  select * 
    from generic_table 
   union all
  select dt,
         out_id,
         'Beta' as ord_type,
         'False' as identifier1,
         0 as Non_Recon_Amnt,
         0 as act_returns
    from generic_table t1
   where not exists
           ( select 1
               from generic_table t2
              where t1.dt = t2.dt
                and t1.out_id = t2.out_id
                and t2.ord_type = 'Beta'
           )
     and t1.ord_type = 'Alpha'
)
select orig.dt,
       orig.out_id,
       orig.ord_type,
       orig.identifier1,
       orig.Non_Recon_Amnt,
       case when orig.ord_type = 'Alpha' then 0
            when orig.ord_type = 'Beta' then orig.act_returns
                                             + 
                                             coalesce(alpha_to_beta.act_returns, 0)
            else orig.act_returns
        end as act_returns
  from with_mocked_missing_beta_record orig
  left
  join with_mocked_missing_beta_record alpha_to_beta
    on orig.dt = alpha_to_beta.dt
   and orig.out_id = alpha_to_beta.out_id
   and orig.ord_type = 'Beta'
   and alpha_to_beta.ord_type = 'Alpha'
order 
    by orig.dt,
       orig.ord_type;
```

| dt | out_id | ord_type | Non_Recon_Amnt | (No column name) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-12-16 | 01 | Alpha | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-12-16 | 01 | Beta | 2 | 7 |
| 2023-12-16 | 01 | Gamma | 3 | 5 |
| 2023-12-17 | 01 | Beta | 4 | 6 |
| 2023-12-17 | 01 | Gamma | 5 | 7 |
| 2023-12-18 | 01 | Alpha | 6 | 0 |
| 2023-12-18 | 01 | Beta | 0 | 8 |
| 2023-12-18 | 01 | Gamma | 7 | 9 |

**Edit:** A bit more brief. I'd be surprised if Redshift didn't support this. Same idea as above but just looks across the window instead of with a self join.

```
with with_mocked_missing_beta_record as (
  select * 
    from generic_table 
   union all
  select dt,
         out_id,
         'Beta' as ord_type,
         'False' as identifier1,
         0 as Non_Recon_Amnt,
         0 as act_returns
    from generic_table t1
   where not exists
           ( select 1
               from generic_table t2
              where t1.dt = t2.dt
                and t1.out_id = t2.out_id
                and t2.ord_type = 'Beta'
           )
     and t1.ord_type = 'Alpha'
)
select dt,
       out_id,
       ord_type,
       identifier1,
       Non_Recon_Amnt,
       case when ord_type = 'Alpha' then 0
            when ord_type = 'Beta' then 
                 act_returns + 
                   max(case when ord_type = 'Alpha' then act_returns else 0 end)
                     over ( partition by dt, out_id)
            else act_returns
        end as act_returns
  from with_mocked_missing_beta_record
 order 
    by dt,
       ord_type
```

Comment: @MatBailie Appreciate the catch

Comment: @MatBailie Oh, right right. I thought you were suggesting that for logical reasons and I didn't quite follow.

Comment: Some alternatives "for fun" ; https://dbfiddle.uk/aqJQkIB5 *(Because I'm still crying inside about Redshift not having LATERAL JOIN)*